# How to avoid android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException when using WorkManager?

Tags: android

All the while, we are using `WorkManager`'s Foreground Service to help us perform long running task

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running (I implement my code based on Java example given in the guideline)

Now, we are porting our app to API 31.

We get the following runtime error in some case

> Fatal Exception:
> android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException:
> Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground
> false: service
> com.xxx.yyy/androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService

The full crash log is

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service com.xxx.yyy/androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService
   at android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException$1.createFromParcel(ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.java:54)
   at android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException$1.createFromParcel(ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.java:50)
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:3349)
   at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2436)
   at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2425)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2408)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2350)
   at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setServiceForeground(IActivityManager.java:7194)
   at android.app.Service.startForeground(Service.java:786)
   at androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService$1.run(SystemForegroundService.java:124)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8191)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
```

Our code snippet in using `WorkManager`'s Foreground Service is as follow.

```
public class XXXApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements DefaultLifecycleObserver {
    @Override
    public void onPause(LifecycleOwner owner) {
        startCloudWorker();
    }
}

public static void startCloudWorker() {
    OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest =
            new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(CloudWorker.class)
                    .setInitialDelay(..., TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    ...
                    .build();

    WorkManager workManager = getWorkManager();
    workManager.enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest);
}

public class CloudWorker extends Worker {
    public CloudWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        final ForegroundInfo foregroundInfo = createForegroundInfo(...)

        setForegroundAsync(foregroundInfo);
        
        // Some busy job here...

        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

Most of the time, the above code will work.

However, sometimes, based on crash report, it fails with exception `android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException`

I guess during that period, our app has gone into background mode, and hitting new limitation (Cannot launch Foreground service when app is in background mode)

I was wondering, is there a way, to at least avoid such exception. For instance, if detect the app is in background mode, then we wouldn't start the foreground service?

---

If I test under emulator, I would get the following notification

[image]

Comment: Ah, how unlucky it is going, why no answers to the question... I have the same problem, still no solution